# Sum of principal ideals in a commutative rng

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, rngs

Let's define the principal ideal of an element $a$ of a commutative ring $R$ with or without identity as  $\langle a \rangle = R \cdot a + \mathbb Za$.

It looks like with this definition $\langle a \rangle \cdot \langle b \rangle = \langle a \cdot b \rangle$ in any commutative ring/rng:

- $r \cdot (ab) + n(ab) = a \cdot (r \cdot b + nb) = (r \cdot a + na) \cdot b \implies \langle a \cdot b \rangle \subseteq \langle a \rangle \cdot \langle b \rangle$;
- $(x \cdot a + na) \cdot (y \cdot b + mb) = (xy + mx + ny) \cdot (ab) + mn(ab) \implies \langle a \rangle \cdot \langle b \rangle \subseteq \langle a \cdot b \rangle$.

I am trying to check the properties for the sum of principal ideals:

- $r \cdot (a + b) + n(a + b) = (r \cdot a + na) + (r \cdot b + nb) \implies \langle a + b \rangle \subseteq \langle a \rangle + \langle b \rangle$.

Question:

In which types of rings/rngs $\langle a \rangle + \langle b \rangle \subseteq \langle a + b \rangle$ (and, therefore, $\langle a \rangle + \langle b \rangle = \langle a + b \rangle$)?

Comment: In the case of rings, it's only true for fields: given $x \neq 0$, take $a=1$ and $b = x -1$ to conclude that $x$ is invertible.

Comment: @RobArthan I am trying to apply your logic to $x = 0$: for any principal ideal $(a)$ there is a principal ideal $(-a)$ such that $(a) + (-a) = (a)$, and $(a - a) = (0)$; then $(a) = (a) + (-a) = (a - a) = (0)$; $(a) = (0)$ for any principal ideal $(a)$; therefore, the ring is trivial (zero ring). Is this correct?

Comment: That's much better than the suggestion in my comment. Your argument shows that $(a) + (b) = (a + b)$ holds for all $a$ and $b$ iff $R = \{0\}$. You should write it up as an answer to your question.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you. I am not sure if I should write the answer since I was asking the question and you provided the hint. Can we just close the question?

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable. It's a good question and will likely be useful to others and you deserve the credit for the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help from Rob Arthan:

$\langle a \rangle + \langle b \rangle = \langle a + b \rangle$ for any $a$ and $b$ of a commutative ring/rng $R$ if and only if $R = \{ 0 \}$.

Proof:

- If $R = \{ 0 \}$, then $\langle 0 \rangle$ is the only principal ideal of $R$;
  $\langle 0 \rangle + \langle 0 \rangle = \langle 0 + 0 \rangle = \langle 0 \rangle$.
- Assuming $\langle a \rangle + \langle b \rangle = \langle a + b \rangle$ for any elements $a$ and $b$ of $R$;
  Then, for an element $x$: $\langle x \rangle = \langle x \rangle + \langle -x \rangle = \langle x + (-x) \rangle = \langle 0 \rangle$;
  $x$ is an element of $\langle x \rangle$, however the only element of $\langle 0 \rangle$ is $0$;
  Therefore, $x = 0$ for an arbitrary element $x$ of $R$.